# Bash: print each input string in a new line

Tags: bash, newline, echo

With `xargs`, I give `echo` several strings to print. Is there any way to display **each** given string in a **new line**?

```
find . something -print0 | xargs -r0 echo
```

I'm sure this is super simple, but I can't find the right key words to google it, apparently.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
find . something -print0 | xargs -r0 printf "%s\n"
```

Clearly, `find` can also print one per line happily without help from `xargs`, but presumably this is only part of what you're after.  The `-r` option makes sense; it doesn't run the `printf` command if there's nothing to print, which is a useful and sensible extension in GNU [`xargs`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#xargs-options) compared with POSIX [`xargs`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/xargs.html) which always requires the command to be run at least once.  (The `-print0` option to `find` and the `-0` option to `xargs` are also GNU extensions compared with POSIX.)

Most frequently these days, you don't need to use `xargs` with `find` because POSIX [`find`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) supports the `+` operand in place of the legacy `;` to `-exec`, which means you can write:

```
find . something -exec printf '%s\n' {} +
```

When the `+` is used, `find` collects as many arguments as will fit conveniently on a command line and invokes the command with those arguments.  In this case, there isn't much point to using `printf` (or `echo`), but in general, this handles the arguments correctly, one argument per file name, even if the file name contains blanks, tabs, newlines, and other awkward characters.

Comment: Thanks! Yup, it's only part of a longer command line I'm trying to put together. I edited the original post to include `-print0`

Answer (score 11):

Here's one way with `echo` to get what you want.

```
find . something -print0 | xargs -r0 -n1 echo
```

`-n1` tells `xargs` to consume 1 command line argument with each invocation of the command (in this case, `echo`)